# Google Maps cannot start in Chrome

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome

I've an application that has been working for months, suddenly it doesn't work on Chrome but it works in Firefox.

It happens with Google Maps Version "3.16.11" and Chrome "34.0.1847.131"

Chrome console says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function VM160:76
(anonymous function) VM160:76
xf.main main.js:54
(anonymous function) main.js:26
(anonymous function) main.js:12
(anonymous function) main.js:26
M main.js:11
(anonymous function) main.js:26
tf.(anonymous function).ff main.js:25
uf.(anonymous function).md main.js:26
yf main.js:26
(anonymous function)
```

Any ideas? Does anybody else have the same issue as me?

Comment: Definitely is a Google Maps issue, It works with the version  "3.15.18"

Comment: What does _your_ code look like that generates this error?  Can you provide a jsfiddle?